# Take Top(X) of each grouped item in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I'm trying to take the Top(X) recors for every unique item in a column.

Example:

```
Inspections
InspectionId | RestaurauntName | InspectionDate
------------------------------------------------
1               Mom&Pop           10/10/12
2               SandwichesPlace   10/10/12
3               Mom&Pop           10/10/11
4               SandwichesPlace   10/10/11
5               Mom&Pop           10/10/10
6               SandwichesPlace   10/10/10
7               BurgerPlace       10/10/11
8               BurgerPlace       10/10/09
9               BurgerPlace       10/10/08
```

If I pass the value of '2' as the parameter I want the records 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8 returned.

In this example snippet I'm attempting to take a few records for each 'restaurantName'.

```
    public IQueryable<Inspections> 
    GetLatestInspectionDatesForAllRestaurants(int numRecords) {

    IQueryable<Inspections> inspections= _session.Query<Inspections>()
                            .GroupBy(r=> r.RestaurauntName)
                            .SelectMany(g => g
                                            .OrderBy(r => r.InspectionDate)
                                            .Take(numRecords));

            return inspections;
     }
```

Unfortunately I'm getting this error.

```
      Query Source could not be identified:
      ItemName = g, ItemType = System.Linq.IGrouping`2
```

The exception triggers at this point in code

```
  var inspections = _inspectionRepository.GetLatestInspectionDatesForAllRestaurants(2).ToList();
```

What am I missing?

### EDIT

After running a test I have confirmed the query runs fine in LINQ-To-Objects. Is it possible NHibernate.Linq is still incomplete in this area? I did a slightly different query (below) and got a not implemented exception.

```
       .GroupBy(r=> r.RestaurauntName)
                            .Select(g => g.First()).Take(5)
```

If I drop the Take(5) from the end I get the following (reminder this is a sample, my PK is Id in my real case).

```
  {"Column '.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."}
```

Do I need to learn to use create criteria or something?

Comment: Change `IQueryable<Inspections> inspections` to `var inspections` and see if its the same.

Comment: Yes, it is the same Bob, good suggestion though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I got the SQL I needed generated, it took some research and whatnot. I'm convinced my original issue had to do with LINQ and NHibernate, though that last query Robert posted was technically correct as a workaround.

This will generate a single SQL script due to the nature of IQueryable not enumerating until necessary. The SQL itself generates 'Where Exists' clause.

```
public IQueryable<Inspections> 
GetLatestInspectionDatesForAllRestaurants(int numRecords)
{
     var subQuery =  _session.Query<Inspections>()
     .OrderByDescending(x => x.InspectionDate);

     var inspections = _session.Query<Inspections>()
                        .Where(x => subQuery.Where(y => y.InspectionDate == 
                               x.InspectionDate).Take(numRecords).Contains(x))
                        .OrderBy(x => x.WellDataId);
    return inspections;
}
```

There it is, hopefully it helps someone else eventually.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Inspections{
    public int InspectionId {get;set;}
    public string RestaurantName {get;set;}
    public DateTime InspectionDate {get;set;}
}
void Main()
{
    var result=GetLatestInspectionDatesForAllRestaurants(2);
    result.Dump();
}
public IQueryable<Inspections> 
    GetLatestInspectionDatesForAllRestaurants(int numRecords) {
        var i = new[]{
        new Inspections{InspectionId=1,RestaurantName="Mom&Pop",InspectionDate=DateTime.Parse("10/10/12")},
        new Inspections{InspectionId=2,RestaurantName="SandwichesPlace",InspectionDate=DateTime.Parse("10/10/12")},
        new Inspections{InspectionId=3,RestaurantName="Mom&Pop",InspectionDate=DateTime.Parse("10/10/11")},
        new Inspections{InspectionId=4,RestaurantName="SandwichesPlace",InspectionDate=DateTime.Parse("10/10/11")},
        new Inspections{InspectionId=5,RestaurantName="Mom&Pop",InspectionDate=DateTime.Parse("10/10/10")},
        new Inspections{InspectionId=6,RestaurantName="SandwichesPlace",InspectionDate=DateTime.Parse("10/10/10")},
        new Inspections{InspectionId=7,RestaurantName="BurgerPlace",InspectionDate=DateTime.Parse("10/10/11")},
        new Inspections{InspectionId=8,RestaurantName="BurgerPlace",InspectionDate=DateTime.Parse("10/10/09")},
        new Inspections{InspectionId=9,RestaurantName="BurgerPlace",InspectionDate=DateTime.Parse("10/10/08")}
    };
    var result=i.GroupBy(g=>g.RestaurantName).SelectMany(g=>g.OrderByDescending(d=>d.InspectionDate).Take(2));
    return result.AsQueryable();
    }
```

This runs just fine, so I am assuming that you are having a problem with the lifetime of your original queryable.  Try the following:

```
public IQueryable<Inspections> 
  GetLatestInspectionDatesForAllRestaurants(int numRecords)
{

  IQueryable<Inspections> inspections= _session.Query<Inspections>()
                        .GroupBy(r=> r.RestaurauntName)
                        .SelectMany(g => g
                                        .OrderByDescending(r => r.InspectionDate)
                                        .Take(numRecords));

  return inspections.ToList().AsQueryable();
}
```

Here's a 3rd option, that performs badly, but should eliminate NHibernate from the equation:

```
public IQueryable<Inspections> 
  GetLatestInspectionDatesForAllRestaurants(int numRecords)
{

  IQueryable<Inspections> inspections= _session.Query<Inspections>().ToList()
                        .GroupBy(r=> r.RestaurauntName)
                        .SelectMany(g => g
                                        .OrderByDescending(r => r.InspectionDate)
                                        .Take(numRecords));

  return inspections.ToList().AsQueryable();
}
```

Comment: Notice that I changed the OrderBy to OrderByDescending so you get the numRecords latest values rather than the numRecords earliest.

Comment: Only because the function Seth had returns an IQueryable.

Comment: Hi Robert, I agree that this function should run, however I'm still getting the error.

Comment: I followed your first example, the query worked for me on the new list "i" as well. It has to be related to the NHibernate implementation of Linq doesn't it?

Comment: Could be.  I've never actually used NHibernate.  It's likely either a bug in their LINQ implementation, or possibly something particular to their implementation that I'm not aware of.  I'll add a 3rd option, which will run very poorly, but should get around any NHibernate issues, just be aware, it will perform badly.

Comment: I'm not familiar with it either, just started with it this month. Yeah, That will get the correct list, but I'm looking at a table with 1mil+ records.

Comment: Ah, well then performing badly would likely kill you.  I was hoping perhaps this was a small project, looking at a couple hundred records, and you could worry about the performance at a later point.  Guess that isn't the case.

Comment: What version of NHibernate are you using? Looks like there was a bug in versions between 3.2 and 3.3.1 regarding it parsing GroupBy. https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3125

Comment: Also https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2833 might affect the query if it implements .Take the same way it implements .Where, https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3001 would definitely affect this query as well.  Looks like 3.3.3GA is the first release to fix all these bugs.  Released March 17, 2013.

Comment: I just checked that, 3.3.3 is what I'm on already. Bah. 

I'm currently trying to see if its possible without the group by at all.